# Problem booting windows 7 while ubuntu installed alongside withit

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows, dual-boot, boot-loader

I dual boot my machine by shrinking the size of partition and creating un-allocated space through windows 7 and at that un-allocated space I installed ubuntu after the complete installation of Ubuntu 18.04 I restart my laptop than the GRUB boot menu showed up. But there was only option for booting Ubuntu not the windows7.

[image]

Although all windows partitions can be accessed through ubuntu but at the starting no option is showing for booting window in the GRUB boot menu.
I tried to rectify this error by using command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

But that did not work well. I run the following command as well:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

[image]

the result is shown in which all the partitions are available

So, kindly provide me with the solution of that problem.

Comment: Looks like you moved your boot partition /sda1 , and bad things are known to happen if you do. The boot partition normally starts near the beginning of the drive, but it's now after the end of /sda2 .Suggest you make a disk-to-disk copy of that drive with Clonezilla https://clonezilla.org/ to a disk at least 554GB in size before trying to resolve this, if you did not have a complete backup before you started.